# How to use Class construct a TableModel in Java

Tags: java, tablemodel

I want use a class to construct a `TableModel`. I know how to use method return a `TableModel`.
But I wonder how to use class to construct a `TableModel`.
So far I failed.  The `dataset` did not get all the value through data. So `dataset` is null. Similarly `columnNamesCount` also is null.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot read the array length because "this.columnNamesCount" is null
    at MyTableModel.getColumnCount(castToModel.java:57)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.JTable.createDefaultColumnsFromModel(JTable.java:1297)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.JTable.tableChanged(JTable.java:4391)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.JTable.setModel(JTable.java:3693)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.JTable.<init>(JTable.java:647)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.JTable.<init>(JTable.java:588)
    at castToModel.<init>(castToModel.java:14)
    at Main.main(Main.java:54)
```

After the `while loop` the data is stored all the value.

```
class MyTableModel extends AbstractTableModel {
    public Object[][] dataset;
    public int columnCount;
    public String[] columnNames;
    public String[] columnNamesCount;
    String query = "select * from emp";
    void MyTableModel() throws SQLException {
        Statement stmt = Main.connection.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE, ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);
        //PreparedStatement stmt = Main.connection.prepareStatement(query);
        ResultSet resultSet = stmt.executeQuery(query);
        ResultSetMetaData resultSetMetaData = resultSet.getMetaData();
        columnCount = resultSetMetaData.getColumnCount();
        columnNames = new String[columnCount];
        for (int ii = 1; ii <= columnCount; ii++) {
            columnNames[ii-1] = resultSetMetaData.getColumnName(ii);
        }
        resultSet.last();
        int rowCount = resultSet.getRow();
        resultSet.beforeFirst();
        Object[][] data = new Object[rowCount][columnCount];
        int currentRow = 0;
        while (resultSet.next()) {
            for (int currentColumn = 1; currentColumn <= columnCount; currentColumn++) {
                data[currentRow][currentColumn - 1] = resultSet.getObject(currentColumn);
            }
            currentRow++;
        }
        dataset = data;
        columnNamesCount=columnNames;
    }

    @Override
    public int getRowCount() {return dataset.length;}
    @Override
    public int getColumnCount() {return columnNamesCount.length;}
    @Override
    public Object getValueAt(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {return dataset[rowIndex][columnIndex];}
    public Class getColumnClass(int c) { return getValueAt(0, c).getClass(); }
    public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int col) {return true;}
}
```

Edit1: My casttoModel code:

```
public class castToModel {
    public castToModel(){
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Demo");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        TableModel model = new MyTableModel();
        JTable table = new JTable(model);
        frame.add(table);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);}
}
```

Comment: I am not sure what you want to do here. Do you want to replace Object[][] dataset with Employee[] dataset?

Comment: I want `JTable table = new JTable(new MyTableModel());` this line (live in another class ) works. But this line will not working. Which means that My code cannot construct a correct TableModel.

Comment: I see. I just don't understand why dataset can be null if data = new Object[rowCount][columnCount]. Are you getting any exception?

Comment: `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot read the array length because "this.columnNamesCount" is null
 at MyTableModel.getColumnCount(castToModel.java:57)
 at java.desktop/javax.swing.JTable.createDefaultColumnsFromModel(JTable.java:1297)
 at java.desktop/javax.swing.JTable.tableChanged(JTable.java:4391)
 at java.desktop/javax.swing.JTable.setModel(JTable.java:3693)
 at java.desktop/javax.swing.JTable.<init>(JTable.java:647)
 at java.desktop/javax.swing.JTable.<init>(JTable.java:588)
 at castToModel.<init>(castToModel.java:14)
 at Main.main(Main.java:54)`

Comment: What class is this castToModel.java? Is it yours?

Comment: This article is in portuguese, but I think you can use google translator on it. I think it provides a very complete example on how to do what you need - https://www.devmedia.com.br/implementando-seu-proprio-tablemodel/31865 - Please notice that it does not initialize the structure in the constructor, what I believe it is an idea you could try.

Comment: Are you sure that the exception is generated by the code you’ve shown us?  It should not be possible for columnNamesCount to be null, since it is the same array as columnNames, which is initialized with `new String[columnCount]`.  In Java, the `new` operator cannot return null under any circumstances.

Comment: @VGR `ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery(query);
        rs.last();
        int count = rs.getRow();
        System.out.println(count);`  so the return result is more 2. So the database don't have issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the code in your question:

```java
void MyTableModel() throws SQLException {
```

This is ***not*** a constructor.

This is a constructor:

```java
public MyTableModel() throws SQLException {
```

The java compiler treats `void MyTableModel()` as a regular method that does not return a value and has package access. This means that class `MyTableModel` does not declare a constructor. In that case, the compiler will add an empty constructor like below:

```java
public MyTableModel() {
    super();
}
```

You need to remove the word `void` and replace it with the appropriate [access modifier](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html).

Also, in the code in your question, you never initialize `columnNamesCount`. Hence it is null and hence method `getColumnCount()` throws `NullPointerException`. I think method `getColumnCount()` should be as follows:

```java
@Override
public int getColumnCount() {
    return columnNames.length;
}
```